# Using autodocs with WCF REST Service Template 40

Tags: wcf, rest, autodoc

I'm looking for a documentation tool for REST services created using the 'WCF REST Service Template 40' and came across Autodocs (http://autodocs.codeplex.com/), however I'm not sure if they'll work together....

Anyone who has made it work or any suggestions to another tool to use for documentation (It's rather important that's it's the REST services which gets documented, and not the C# API)

TIA

Søren

Answer (score 1):

Working with Autodocs for any length of time it becomes pretty obvious that the support is not there for the project yet.  Its just too young.  I ran into a few errors that stopped me from pursuing it after I found the documentation help methods integrated into WCF 4.0

The post explaining my error:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wcf/thread/b196a05f-2d28-449e-9620-a74f939a625f

WCF Web HTTP Service Help Page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx

Hope that helps you.